# Set CWD to Source Directory, as opposed to Build Directory

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, cross-platform, qmake

In C, when using the `FILE` struct from `stdio.h`, the current working directory will be relative to the build directory if the programmer attempts to open a file.

Is there a setting of some sort (maybe a compiler flag) which I can use to allow the CWD to be set to the source directory at compile or run time? Preferably a method that is cross-platform from Windows to *nix, but if that's not doable let's just say *nix.

I'm working in Linux currently, with GCC/G++, using qmake without the Qt libraries.

Also, the main reason I'm using the C `FILE` IO  method as opposed to C++'s `std::ifstream` is just personal preference, in case anyone asks.

Comment: In what environment are paths relative to the build directory?  That's pretty exotic.  In most situations, the standard behavior is exactly as you desire.

Comment: That's interesting, actually: I'm using Qt Creator, with my build settings set to debug. When I tested it using `std::ifstream`, I was able to open the file using a relative path. With `FILE`, however, it would set the cwd to the build directory by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your .pro file you can define the source directory as a macro, then `chdir()` to it in your source code.

```
# myproject.pro
DEFINES+=SRCDIR=\\\"$$PWD\\\"

# myapp.cpp
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (chdir(SRCDIR)) {
        perror("chdir to " SRCDIR);
    }
    // ... rest of code
}
```

Getting it to work on Windows might involve fiddling with the number of backslashes in the .pro file.